# Safari Crashes When The API Response Is 25 MB

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, angularjs, safari

I'm developing a website which should support by iOS safari browser.

Safari browser get crashed when the website do an ajax API call which has 25MB of JSON response data. Can you please suggest me how to resolve this issue?

iOS version tested: 7.0 and 7.1
Device: iPad

I have also noted that the same behavior happens (throws 'webkit2ebprocess.exe error') in desktop safari browser too. It even get the OK response for that API in the debugger tool of network tab, but crash when pulling the large data before it complete. 
OS: Windows 7

I'm using $http to make the API call lile below:

```
           $http({
                url: urlstring,
                method: "GET",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                dataType: 'json'
            }).success(function (data) {
                data = data.replace("callback(", "");
                data = data.replace("JSON_CALLBACK(", "");
                data = data.substring(0, data.length - 1);
                data = '{"data": ' + data + '}';
                var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
                newGroupPromise.resolve(data1);

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                newGroupPromise.resolve('error');
            });
```

Comment: Can you paste some code? How are you making the ajax request? using $http or jquery?

Comment: 25MB of JSON data!? That would mean that the browser would use 25MB of RAM only for the JSON data to parse it and then additional memory for the data objects. This is **WAY** too much for a mobile device. You should rethink your approach and lower the amount of data send per API request dramatically.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to ask why is there 25 MB of JSON data to push to the client? If everything is going to presented on the same page then I don't think any sane human being will be able to interpret so much data at a time. Even if there's going to be some CSS/JS magic, that's too much data to be processed first before displaying the results. Is this a case of poorly handed pagination?